# Restricting the usage of classes C#

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

I have a plugin sdk for an application I've made in c#, I want people to be able to modify it as needed with the sdk, but I do not want them to be able to access certain c# features (sockets/threading, etc). Is there a way I can stop them from using these?

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are wanting to restrict. Please edit your question and add more details explaining what you want to do. Perhaps include a code example of something you would like to block a user of your SDK from doing.

Comment: I just want to restrict some of the .Net classes. For example, i want to know how i can make it so any project with my sdk files .dll added will throw an error when they try to do something like. "using System.Threading or using System.Sockets; The reason for this is the SDK will be publically available and I do not want people to be able to do malicious things with my sdk such as keylogging etc.

Comment: It is a possible, too large a topic to tackle in an SO post.  Google ".net sandboxing" to get ahead.

Comment: Thank you hans my friend that was what i needed indeed.